# How to include log-in credentials in GET/POST methods?

Tags: http, post, get

I have set a `.htpasswd` in my webpage which is working fine, because the data included is sensitive.

When I try to do something like this:

```
www.mywebpage.com/example.php?var=1&set=0
```

It does reply an expected error msg:

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
> document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
> bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
> credentials required.

How do I include user & password in the above request?

Comment: Send the username and password in the post body. Read more from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562675/proper-way-to-send-username-and-password-from-client-to-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://user:password@www.mywebpage.com/example.php?var=1&set=0
Take care for escaping characters if necessary.
(see RFC3986 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-18 )

Note: User name and password likely is logged in the webserver's logs as plain text.

Comment: See also https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Authentifizierung#Basic_Authentication. Most API's provide possibilities to provide user and password in a more secure way (not logged, encrypted).

Comment: I am doing this from a SIM908 - GSM module with AT commands, so there are not any built-in ways to send user and password in a more secure way.

Comment: When I try this in the browser it is working, but when I insert it on the module I get an error code "DNS ERROR"