# Volley GET request with json data

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to user Android's Volley library to emulate the following cURL request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d '{"password":"password"}' https://0.0.0.0:5000/staging/api/v2.0/supporter/name=Steven
```

which works as expected, but the following code does not work for android:

```
public void getSupporterByName(String name, String password, @NonNull final APIRequestCallback<Supporter> callback){
    try {
        JSONObject job = new JSONObject();
        job.put("password", password);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getAPIEndpoint() + "supporter/name=" + name, job, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                callback.onSuccess(parseSupporter(response.toString()));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                callback.onFailure(error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> currs = super.getHeaders();
                Map<String, String> map = currs != null ? new HashMap<>(super.getHeaders()) : new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return map;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(req);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        callback.onFailure(ex);
    }
}
```

I keep getting a 400 bad request from the API, which I know is because the API isn't seeing the JSONObject that's sent across and therefore not able to validate the password. Is there a way to make a `GET` request with a JSON body using Volley?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question more or less boiled down to this question: [Proper way to send username and password from client to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562675/proper-way-to-send-username-and-password-from-client-to-server)

As per the recommendation, I used a POST request instead of GET.